# Using unknown type in abstract base class definition

Tags: c++, oop

I have an abstract base class `IThingDoer`, with a `virtual` method `doThingWithData`. What I want is to have concrete classes of `IThingDoer` implement `doThingWithData(&someType dat)`, except that the variable type of `dat` (i.e. what `someType` is) varies between different concrete classes.

For example:

```
class IThingDoer {
public:
    virtual void doThingWithData(&someType dat); //??
};

struct Foo {
    int foo1;
    double foo2;
};

class FooThingDoer : public IThingDoer {
public:
    void doThingWithData(&Foo dat){
        std::cout << dat.foo1
    }
};

struct Bar {
    float bar1[2];
};

class BarThingDoer : public IThingDoer {
public:
    void doThingWithData(&Bar dat){
        std::cout << (dat.bar1[0] + dat.bar1[1]);
    }
};
```

I've tried having `Foo` and `Bar` both inherit from another base data class: (I've changed what actually happens to simplify the example a bit)

```
class BaseData{
public:
    int baseData = 1;
};

class IThingDoer{
public:
    virtual void doThingWithData(BaseData dat) = 0;
};

class FooData : public BaseData {
public:
    int otherData = 5;
};

class FooThingDoer : public IThingDoer {
public:
    void doThingWithData(BaseData dat){
        std::cout << dat.otherData;
    }
};

int main()
{
    FooThingDoer a = FooThingDoer();
    FooData dat = FooData();
    a.doThingWithData(dat);

    return 0;
}
```

However, this doesn't work - the compiler can't find `dat.otherData` since there is no `otherData` in the `BaseData` type. Changing `BaseData` to `FooData` in `FooThingDoer.doThingWithData` doesn't work either, since that just causes it to overload the name and not actually implement the virtual function in `IThingDoer`.

I also looked at templates, but (from the point of view of a relatively inexperienced programmer) it looks like templates are used mostly just to reduce the need for overloading functions for every different possible type.

To be clear, the unknown datatypes are only unknown to the abstract class; they would be known at compile-time.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

---

Appendix: I might be dealing with an XY problem; for this reason I'm putting some additional context here.

In the bigger picture, this code is going to run on different pieces of hardware, with different sensors and things that it needs to control. The different ThingDoers implement the specific functionality that needs to happen, but in all cases every ThingDoer can be treated as a black box that takes some data structure as input, and performs some actions as output, with the specific input data structure varying between different ThingDoers.

As I understand it, to improve code reuse etc. in the rest of the program, each ThingDoer should inherit from an abstract class that describes this black box functionality, and the rest of the code should work with this interface. I plan on having separate objects prepare the actual data structure that ThingDoer takes as input; again I would have one preparer object per hardware type.

Then, depending on which piece of hardware I'm compiling for, I would include different header files (containing the specific ThingDoer etc. I need) in the compilation. Since at compile time there's a specific ThingDoer and corresponding input preparer that gets used, I figured that the types would be known at compile time so there isn't any dynamic typing.

Comment: Inheritance and polymorphism is perhaps not the correct solution for your problem. Perhaps consider templates and template specialization? Or perhaps go back to your requirements and analysis of them and attempt to improve the design?

Comment: You can use templated `IThingDoer`

Comment: Unless there is some reason for `someType` to be polymorphic - and provide a set of operations that make sense to your `IThingDoer` class and derived classes -  your design is wrong.     Try using templates.   Then the template can be specialised as needed for particular types of data,

Comment: `someType` doesn't need to be polymorphic; it's a placeholder if anything, and it sounds like templates are what deal with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use template for static polymorphism.

```
#include <iostream>


template <class T>
class IThingDoer {
public:
    virtual void doThingWithData(T dat) = 0;
};

struct Foo {
    int foo1;
    double foo2;
};

class FooThingDoer : public IThingDoer<Foo> {
public:
    void doThingWithData(Foo dat) {
        std::cout << dat.foo1;
    }
};

struct Bar {
    float bar1[2];
};

class BarThingDoer : public IThingDoer<Bar> {
public:
    void doThingWithData(Bar dat) {
        std::cout << (dat.bar1[0] + dat.bar1[1]);
    }
};

int main()
{
    FooThingDoer a = FooThingDoer();
    Foo foo;
    foo.foo1 = 5;
    foo.foo2 = 5.5;
    a.doThingWithData(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

But you example can used too (u can cast only address, not static object):

```
#include <iostream>

class BaseData {
public:
    int baseData = 1;
};

class IThingDoer {
public:
    virtual void doThingWithData(BaseData& dat) = 0;
};

class FooData : public BaseData {
public:
    int otherData = 5;
};

class FooThingDoer : public IThingDoer {
public:
    void doThingWithData(BaseData& dat) {
        std::cout << ((FooData&) dat).otherData;
    }
};

int main()
{
    FooThingDoer a = FooThingDoer();
    FooData dat = FooData();
    a.doThingWithData(dat);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem with the template example is that `FooThingDoer ` and `BarThingDoer` does not inherit from the same class, so it's not possible to have a container with pointers to the common base class since there are no common base class.

Comment: The problem with the cast example is that C-style casts like you do should really be considered a red flag that you're doing something wrong.